# Does dynamic SQL executed by sp_ExecuteSQL typically take longer to parse and compile, especially as the query complexity increases?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, optimization, dynamic-sql, query-performance

I'm noticing a batch of queries that used to parse and compile pretty instantaneously now take anywhere between 5 to 15 seconds to parse and compile as a dynamic SQL statement that is executed with sp_ExecuteSQL. I verified this with the TIME STATISTICS.

My dynamic SQL incorporates a series of closed and re-opened quotes so that values can be dynamically inserted into the statement. Would this make any difference?

Comment: is this being executed in a stored procedure? if it was non-dynamic SQL in a stored proc and now dynamic, then it would have parsed and compiled once in the past and then re-executed (one nice thing about procs) whereas now it might be compiling a lot more. For the first execution, I would expect the dynamic and non-dynamic to take the same amount of time. Dynamic _can_ be cached if you are submitting the same query text and use parameters, but the Dynamic SQL will still need to check permissions on all objects per each execution.

Comment: Yes, it's inside of a stored procedure. The query text in the dynamic SQL does change dependent on one of the parameters passed into the parent procedure, but I'm noticing repeated "parse and compile" times on sequentially repeated runs of the same dynamic SQL query (same parameter passed into the parent procedure.) Could it be taking as long as 15 seconds to check permissions (it's not an exorbitantly long query, but it is maybe around 30 different statements.)